# How to export a modified mesh in skeletal animation In OGRE?

Tags: c++, export, mesh, ogre

I have an ogre code based on skeleton animation . The code has a initial mesh & an underlying skeleton. The mesh is modified as per the changes done to the bones in the skeleton. I intend to save the modified mesh.

I tried the following code:

```
void SaveMesh(){

Ogre::MeshSerializer ser;
ser.exportMesh(entity_->getMesh(), "new.mesh"); 
}
```

I converted the mesh(new.mesh) to xml using ogrexmlconverter & opened the new.mesh.xml in blender. It however showed the unmodified mesh.

How do I export the modified mesh?

Comment: Usually, the mesh is not really modified (the resource of the mesh in your main memory). In the graphics pipeline, probably a shader program transforms the mesh during rendering. In the same sense as a texture is not modified when light effects are applied during rendering.

Comment: are there no APIs in OGRE which can be used to capture the output of the "shader" or update the mesh as the entity changes? can we use animationstate to retrieve the updated mesh?(http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/manual/manual_77.html#Animation-State)

Comment: Worst, case, if those api do not exist, you can still do the following: Read back the skeleton state and then use blender/maya etc and get the rigged model into the same animation state. Then you have what you need, give or take.

Comment: Thanks for you replies. can you suggest any blender APIs. I am new to blender.

Comment: I am able to export the animated skeleton from OGRE. But I couldnt find a way to import it into blender or MAYA.